# Bootstrap stacked nav only one open at a time issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a stacked bootstrap nav menu, and what I would like for it to operate like an accordion. If a user clicks one of the nav containers, I'd like for the rest of them to close...and for the life of me, after multiple attempts...I just can't seem to figure out what to do here...

```
 <ul class="nav nav-stacked home-menu-one" id="stacked-menu">
  <li>
      <a class="nav-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stacked-menu" href="#p2">Shop Styles<div class="caret-container"><span class="caret arrow"></span></div></a>    
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse" id="p1">
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/braided">Braided Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/contemporary">Contemporary Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/country-floral">Country &amp; Floral</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/european">European Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/botanical">Floral Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/southwestern">Geometric</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/search?ky=bCLo8xon6nv1zonqFzee2yahfIC2ogeJtMf8MUvqKZY">Jute Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/theme">Kids Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/search?ky=DiXwkLd_Kxj7oLcmO6VeSegDhqGLIEu6yb0FDhHq0-I">Outdoor Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/shag">Shag</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/solid-tone-on-tone">Tone On Tone</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/traditional">Traditional Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/transitional">Transitional Rugs</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a class="nav-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stacked-menu" href="#p1">Shop Colors<div class="caret-container"><span class="caret arrow"></span></div></a>          
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse" id="p2">
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/beige">Beige</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/black-grey">Black &amp; Grey</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/blue">Blues</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/brown-tan">Brown &amp; Tan</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/gold-yellow">Gold &amp; Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/graysilver">Gray &amp; Silver</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/green">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/ivory-white">Ivory &amp; White</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/multicolor">Multicolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/orange-rust">Orange &amp; Rust</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/purple-pink">Purple &amp; Pink</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/red-burgundy">Red &amp; Burgundy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

Can anyone provide some javacript to make this work as intended? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.nav > li > a').click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().slideUp().parent().siblings().find('ul').slideDown();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.nav > .active > ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-stacked home-menu-one" id="stacked-menu">
  <li class="active">
      <a class="nav-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stacked-menu" href="#p2">Shop Styles<div class="caret-container"><span class="caret arrow"></span></div></a>    
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse" id="p1">
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/braided">Braided Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/contemporary">Contemporary Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/country-floral">Country &amp; Floral</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/european">European Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/botanical">Floral Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/southwestern">Geometric</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/search?ky=bCLo8xon6nv1zonqFzee2yahfIC2ogeJtMf8MUvqKZY">Jute Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/theme">Kids Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/search?ky=DiXwkLd_Kxj7oLcmO6VeSegDhqGLIEu6yb0FDhHq0-I">Outdoor Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/shag">Shag</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/solid-tone-on-tone">Tone On Tone</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/traditional">Traditional Rugs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/style/transitional">Transitional Rugs</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
      <li>
      <a class="nav-container" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#stacked-menu" href="#p1">Shop Colors<div class="caret-container"><span class="caret arrow"></span></div></a>          
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse" id="p2">
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/beige">Beige</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/black-grey">Black &amp; Grey</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/blue">Blues</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/brown-tan">Brown &amp; Tan</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/gold-yellow">Gold &amp; Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/graysilver">Gray &amp; Silver</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/green">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/ivory-white">Ivory &amp; White</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/multicolor">Multicolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/orange-rust">Orange &amp; Rust</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/purple-pink">Purple &amp; Pink</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.example.com/items/color/red-burgundy">Red &amp; Burgundy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    ...
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked beautifully. I owe you a beer.

Comment: ...although I did need to change .nav to the #stacked-menu..but...just adding that for the next guy with this issue. if this pops up on google.

Comment: Javascript on the answer was changed...the original you provided with the above CSS worked ....

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(' #stacked-menu > li > a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    return false;
  });

});

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.nav > li > a').click( function(e) {
  $(this).next().show().parent().siblings().find('ul').hide();
  //or $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This makes the siblings actually dissapear, rather than just "collapse"...although, otherwise it works exactly as I'd like. Any chance you could tweak this a bit?

Comment: try .slideUp() , .slideDown()